# Why are generative and discriminative models called that way?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, terminology, generative-models

In machine learning, if I understand it correctly, a generative classifier is one where we directly model the joint distribution $p(x,y|\theta)$, while in a discriminative classifier we model $p(y|x, \theta)$.

Firstly, I don't understand why they are called that way. Secondly, I don't understand what makes these models different, since we can always use the product rule to get one from the other.

Comment: you are getting confused with your notation - in one case $\theta$ is parameters to model $y|x$ whereas in the other case it is the parameters to model the joint distribution of x and y.

Comment: @seanv507, this still doesnt resolve my confusion

Answer (score 2):

A generative model is so called because it tries to learn the probability distribution that generated the data. For example, the Gaussian mixture model will try to learn the parameters of the Gaussian mixture that best fits the data.

A discriminative model is so called because it tries to learn which values $x$ will map to $y$, so it tries to discriminate among the inputs. Neural networks are an example.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_model):

> Regardless of precise definition, the terminology is because a generative model can be used to "generate" random instances [...] while a discriminative model [...] can be used to "discriminate" the value of the target variable Y, given an observation x.

It is true that a generative model can be used to compute the conditional probability, but the other way around is not true.

So, why do we use discriminative models?

A generative model is typically unsupervised, similarly to clustering. A discriminative model is given a more precise task, just try to predict $y$ given $x$, so it's typically supervised.
If prediction is the only thing you care about (as you do in classification tasks), discriminative models will try to solve that problem more directly and might perform better.

Answer (score 0):

Generative classifiers learn how class could generate some data. Given the observation they return the class most likely to have generated the observation. Take for example Naive Bayes, it samples class from $P(y)$ and then words are generated by sampling from $P(x|y)$. $P(x|y)$ is learned on training corpus, treating every word independently - frequency of every word in concatenated class documents. And you can imagine generating document for every class by sampling from this distribution(word salad but meaningful ones). If you think about it in terms of vector multiplication, then words from input are bag of words vector multiplied by one of the word frequency vector, lets call them weight vectors, depending on which class we choose, and then results are compared to get the most probable class.

Discriminative classifiers learns what features from the input are most useful to discriminate between the different possible classes. For example Logistic Regresssion weights every input feature, sums it and apply sigmoid function. Weights are learned by gradient descent. In terms of vector multiplication, then input text - bag ogf words vector, is multiplied by weight vector. So in this case we have only one weight vector instead of multiple in case of Naive Bayes. However this vector cannot help us in generating any sensible input, if we decide one day that we want to.

I hope it helps in understanding how big consequences are by simply calculating $P(X|Y)$ instead of $P(Y|X)$